# Unable to compile beclock on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, kde, cmake

I was unable to compile beclock on latest Arch, with `yaourt -S bekwinfx-git`:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindXCB.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "XCB", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "XCB" with any of
  the following names:

    XCBConfig.cmake
    xcb-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "XCB" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "XCB_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "XCB" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

And I tried to use `pkgfile` to find these files, and to no avail (I already updated pkgfile cache)

Anyone know how to fix that?

**UPDATE**

Seems like XCB and other X11 libs are already included in compile flags, so removing them doesn't hurt

Comment: After commenting out the offending lines `CMakeLists.txt:9, CMakeLists.txt:10, be.clock/CMakeLists:22` it compiles just fine for me.

Comment: @t-8ch you should definitely put that as an answer ;-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After commenting out the offending lines (`CMakeLists.txt:9`, `CMakeLists.txt:10`, `be.clock/CMakeLists:22`) it compiles just fine for me.